# Enchant does not work on wamp server, compilation error

Tags: php, compilation, enchant

I have enabled enchant on my wamp server(V 2.4.9), I am using PHP(V 5.5.12), when I start the server I get the following warning:

> PHP Startup:enchant: Unable to initialize module Module compiled with
>   module API=20100525, PHP compiled with module API=20121212, Theese
>   options need to match.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It appears the module you are using was compiled in 2010. Look for one compiled later. (12/12/2012)

Comment: When you say wamp v 2.4.9, do you mean: [Wamp server 2.5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/Wampserver%202.5/) which ships apache 2.4.9, php 5.5.12? And did you notice the `Don't Use previous WampServer Extensions/Addons.` warning on that page?

Comment: Yes, Iam using 2.5 wamp server. Original Enchant extension was not working on server

Answer (score 0):

It means your module was compiled for php 5.4 but you're using php 5.5.
You need to look for a compatible php 5.5 version of this module.

see https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.4/Zend/zend_modules.h
and https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.5/Zend/zend_modules.h
(search for ZEND_MODULE_API_NO)

Comment: Where to put this zend_modules.h file?

Comment: It's provided by the php core source code when compiling the extension module.